# Can one stand a child in an aron kodesh in order for the child to kiss the sifrei torah?

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, standing-sitting, ark-aron-kodesh, kavod

Can you place (stand) a 2 year old child on a shelf in an Aron Kodesh which is on the same level as the Sifrei Torah in order for the child to look at and kiss the Sifrei Torah?

Comment: stan, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

[*Shulchan Aruch* YD 282](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=219) prohibits sitting next to a *sefer* because that would be *bizayon* to the *sefer*. It seems to me standing shares the same *din*.

According to rules of *chinuch* I would say that one should not deliberately put a child in such a place, if the child goes on his own, at the age of 2 I would assume take him down (or tell him to...)